# How to open external url in iframe in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i open youtube video link in iframe (or in colorbox, fancybox) `with angularjs` ?
It shows javascript error : 
"`Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`"
Here is an Html code -

```
<a href="{{video_url}}" title="{{video.video_title}}" class="nyroModal">
    {{video_title}}
</a>
```

javascript -

```
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
```

Clicking on above link, it should be opened in iframe .. But it shows error mentioned aboove.
Thanks.

Comment: can you paste your html and js code hear

Comment: It may be worth giving the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) a try, but I don't know what your end goal is.

Comment: are u guys having problems with nyroModal not poping up if HTML element is clicked from a loaded angular element?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control a parent frame, in this case, the browser) from a child iFrame across domains. This breaks the sandbox security of an iframe.

If you have access to both the parent and child frame's code and are on the same domain you could use the HTML5 `postMessage()` command.

For further reading on cross domain communication between iframes see the following:

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes